# Umbraco Active Directory integration

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco and I configured it to use Active Directory for login following the official documentation (https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoDocs/blob/master/Reference/Security/index.md#authenticating-with-active-directory-credentials). The behavior is a bit odd.

Before I configured the AD integration, I was able to to login to Umbraco with the email/password defined upon installation. After the integration, I could login with the same email but with my AD password so I guess that the integration kind of work...

However, now, I'd like some other people to login on the site via their AD credential, however, I have no idea how to achieve that. If I invite user, it creates an account with his email but he has to define a password, so it's not AD integrated. Same thing occurs if I try to create a new user.

So at the end of the day, I have no idea how to integrate reliably AD with Umbraco. Does anyone already achieve this and can give me pointers?

I'm running Umbraco 7.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a User account in Umbraco so that you can assign the necessary permissions etc. This is a standard Umbraco User and needs to correspond to the AD username.  I'm not sure though that the Umbraco User needs a designated password though; it's possible you can just let Umbraco auto-generate the password and they will be able to log in with the AD credentials.

To fully integrate Umbraco with AD in the way you're expecting would require some extra code on your part to query AD and pull in the users, auto-generate and link them to a corresponding Umbraco User with an auto-generated password.  It's doable, just will take some creative coding on your part.

**Update:**

If you look in the Umbraco Log after attempting to log in as an Active Diretory user without a corresponding Umbraco User you will most probably find an error with the following message:

```
The user <UserName> does not exist locally and currently the ActiveDirectoryBackOfficeUserPasswordChecker doesn't support auto-linking, see http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-10181
```

The referenced Issue has more details available: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-10181

Comment: Hi, I indeed saw this link but the thing I was (and maybe still am) missing is the user creation. If I follow your explanation, I have to create the user and use the AD login name as the Umbraco user name? How do I do the link after that if auto linking is not supported. Or maybe auto linking is just the part that creates the user ? Maybe I’ll try to do some code to achieve that, it will be a good opportunity to learn the API. I’ll have a look tomorrow and accept your answer depending on what I achieved. Thanks

Comment: Once you set up the user in Umbraco, provided the username matches what's in AD, they should be able to log in.  I haven't yet looked at the Auto Linking code in Umbraco, but it doesn't look like it creates the user, just associates the Domain User with the corresponding Umbraco User (based on UserName I believe) once they've successfully authenticated.  The missing step is the actual Umbraco User creation.

Comment: I just tried to create a user with the name defined as "DOMAIN\Login" and when I'm done, Umbraco gives me a password to login. First weird thing, I can't login with the password it gave me. Second weird thing, when I try to login with my AD password, it does not work, then when I login with an Umbraco user, I see the error you put in your answer... So it look like that even after having created the user in Umbraco, the link between it and the AD user is not done.

Comment: Hm.  I’ll have to spin up an example site and configure it for my domain for testing - may not have time until next week though